# Magento Adds Quantity That is More Than Available in Stock

Tags: php, magento, addition, stock

I have a weird problem with Magento. Say that I have 5 in quantity of a product in stock.

Then, I navigate to the product's view page.

I enter 6 in Qty box, click "Add to Cart" -> It says "requested quantity not available" as expected.

I enter 5 in Qty box, click "Add to Cart" -> It adds 5 items.

Then again I enter 5 in Qty box, click "Add to Cart" -> It adds 5 more items, 10 items in total which is not available in stock.

When I navigate to cart, it says "requested quantity not available" and does not allow me to checkout.

What may be the problem? I debugged so deep but could not figure it out..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Magento are you on? I just tested this on 1.6.1 and it appears this bug was fixed.

Comment: I'm on 1.5.1.0. I see that there are some other guys with exactly the same problem: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/232025/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like magento checks if quantity is aviable when you add items to cart (and does not care if there are these items in cart) and when you enter cart. You may extend class that makes this check and overload function, that checks quantity.

Comment: It is very basic rule, so I can not imagine that Magento authors can discard this issue. So I think that it is not a general problem. Any idea about where this core function is?